# Unity2D: Frost Effect Animation

Tags: unity

I want to know is there a way of using `Mathf.SmoothStep` to control the float of a variable? You see I downloaded this [package](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/5337) ("Frost Effect by Steven Craeynest") on Unity Asset Store and created a `IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter2D` (in a new script) to control the effect once my player hits an orb, making it slow down but now I want to add an animation. Rather than having it appear of the screen and then disappearing, I want to make the frost effect slowly come in, kinda like controlling the frost amount in the inspector. It is possible, because I tried doing it like this:

(This is attached to orb)

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () { 
}

IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player") {
        //frost.enabled = true; 
        GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<FrostEffect>().enabled = true;
        FrostEffect.valToBeLerped = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1f, FrostEffect.FrostAmount);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.01f);
        FrostEffect.valToBeLerped = Mathf.SmoothStep(1, 0, FrostEffect.FrostAmount);
        GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<FrostEffect>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

But it's still appearing automatically rather than it slowly coming in like an animation. Anyway this is the frost effect script I downloaded from the assets store:

(Attach to the main camera)

```
public static float FrostAmount = 0.3f; //0-1 (0=minimum Frost, 1=maximum frost)
public static float valToBeLerped = 0;
public float EdgeSharpness = 1; //>=1
public float minFrost = 0; //0-1
public float maxFrost = 1; //0-1
public float seethroughness = 0.2f; //blends between 2 ways of applying the frost effect: 0=normal blend mode, 1="overlay" blend mode
public float distortion = 0.1f; //how much the original image is distorted through the frost (value depends on normal map)
public Texture2D Frost; //RGBA
public Texture2D FrostNormals; //normalmap
public Shader Shader; //ImageBlendEffect.shader

private Material material;

private void Awake()
{
    material = new Material(Shader);
    material.SetTexture("_BlendTex", Frost);
    material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", FrostNormals);
}

private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination)
{
    if (!Application.isPlaying)
    {
        material.SetTexture("_BlendTex", Frost);
        material.SetTexture("_BumpMap", FrostNormals);
        EdgeSharpness = Mathf.Max(1, EdgeSharpness);
    }
    material.SetFloat("_BlendAmount", Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.Clamp01(FrostAmount) * (maxFrost - minFrost) + minFrost));
    material.SetFloat("_EdgeSharpness", EdgeSharpness);
    material.SetFloat("_SeeThroughness", seethroughness);
    material.SetFloat("_Distortion", distortion);
    ///Debug.Log("_Distortion: "+ distortion);

    Graphics.Blit(source, destination, material);
}
```

Thank you. :)

**Second Edit**
Because so far this is what I have:

```
        GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent<FrostEffect>().enabled = true;
        float duration = 2f;
        DOTween.To(x => FrostEffect.FrostAmount = x, 0.0f, 0.34f, duration)
            .OnComplete(()=>DOTween.To(x => FrostEffect.FrostAmount = x, 0.34f, 0.0f, duration));
        Time.timeScale = 0.05f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (6.5f);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey sorry was sleeping this side of the world :)

Setting delay can be as simple as adding `.SetDelay(float delay);`

I imagine setting the timescale would be similar, as far as I know DoTween uses it's own timescale (`DOTween.timeScale`) so you could modify it to affect game timescale too.

You should spend some time in the DoTween docs and explore what's possible!

http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php

But I've done it for you here this time, should work fine, hopefully haha.

```
float duration = 1.01f;
float delayBeforeUnfreeze = 3.0f;
float previousTimeScale = Time.timeScale;

//Slow timescale
Time.timeScale = 0.01f;

//Freeze time effect
DOTween.To(x =>FrostEffect.FrostAmount = x, 0.0f, 1.0f, duration)
  .OnComplete(()=>
  { 
    //Unfreeze tween effect
    DOTween.To(x => FrostEffect.FrostAmount = x, 1.0f, 0.0f, duration)
      .SetDelay(delayBeforeUnfreeze);

    //Set timescale back to previous.
    Time.timeScale = previousTimeScale;
  });
```

There are cleaner ways to do this via coroutine but that's another story, which I'm sure you will explore later on :)

Best of luck in your journey!

*To mods: Sorry for another answer but it wouldn't fit in another comment. Let me know if theres anything else I can do to keep the answer clean. Cheers!*

Answer (score 1):

```
FrostEffect.valToBeLerped = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1f, FrostEffect.FrostAmount);
yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.01f);
FrostEffect.valToBeLerped = Mathf.SmoothStep(1, 0, FrostEffect.FrostAmount);
```

This will not start an animation of any sort unfortunately, what's happening here is you're setting the exact value to be FrostAmount, waiting 1.01 seconds and then setting it again. I understand what you're trying to do but it requires some sort of Tweening library.

Try DoTween for your project, it is a truly exceptional package in my opinion: http://dotween.demigiant.com/download.php

Once that's done, replace the above lines with:

```
float duration = 1.01f;
DOTween.To(x => FrostEffect.FrostAmount = x, 0.0f, 1.0f, duration)
.OnComplete(()=>DOTween.To(x => FrostEffect.FrostAmount = x, 1.0f, 0.0f, duration));
```

Make sure to include the using header for DoTween:

```
using DG.Tweening;
```

I haven't checked the above code 100% but I'll have another look when I get back from work. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you it worked, I just have one question is there a way to just make (when the frost comes in) wait for a couple of seconds then use: .OnComplete(()=>DOTween.To(x => FrostEffect.FrostAmount = x, 1.0f, 0.0f, duration)); Thank you for your reply, it really helped!! :)

Comment: Also is there a way not to make the script you gave me affected my time. timescale = to 0.01;. because the orb slows every thing down as well. so when the orb is done (using yield return new waitforseconds) then the script you gave me works. Thank you :)

Comment: Please look above to see my second edit. Thank you

Comment: I've added another answer to answer your other question, hope it helps :)

Comment: Um, Sorry I'm but I got an error when I open up my game. But when I double click on it nothings happening like it doesn't show me where is the errors coming from. This are the errors:   Get_timeScale can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

Comment: Sorry nevermind, I fixed it. :) Thank you once again

Comment: Hi @quaternion sorry about this but could you look at this question for me. Thank you in advance. :) This is the [link](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/129321/unity2d-frost-effect-time-scale)